# Generate an array with specified keys

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have a big question. I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [2] => 566
    [9] => 1946
)
```

I need to generate an array, for this example, the key for array need to be from 1 to 7 random... So for this array the result should be :

```
Array
(
    [1] => 566
    [5] => 566
    [1] => 1946
    [6] => 1946
    [2] => 1946
    [5] => 1946
    [7] => 1946
    [6] => 1946
    [3] => 1946
    [4] => 1946
    [7] => 1946
)
```

So 556 have 2, So I put in the array 2 times with the key random between 1..7. For 1946 the same, this it have 9 from start. And for this id neet to put in an array 9 times with key between 1..7. Help me please. Thx in advance

Comment: I can not make array with some equal keys

Comment: That result is not possible. You can't have an array with multiple of the same key.

Comment: does it have to be the key in that array? could the result be an array of objects maybe? like `[0] => {x:7, number: 566}, [1]=>{x:7, number:1946}`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP array keys are **unique**. So by definition your requirements cannot be met given the specificity of this implementation.

Instead, if you consider that you have two unique values (`566` and `1946`), for which you want to generate an arbitrary number of random values (*not unique*) between `1` and `7`, then the inverse is possible using the values `566` and `1946` as keys.

```
$uniqueValues = [2 => 566, 9 => 1946];
$newValues    = [];

function getRandomNumbers($n, $i, $j)
{
    $values;
    for($s = 0; $s < $n; $s++) {
        $values[] = mt_rand($i, $j);
    }
    return $values;
}

foreach($uniqueValues as $n => $value) {
    $newValues[$value] = getRandomNumbers($n, 1, 7);
}

var_dump($newValues);
```

This should output something similar to the following...

```
array(2) {
  [566]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(6)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1946]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(6)
    [3]=>
    int(6)
    [4]=>
    int(5)
    [5]=>
    int(2)
    [6]=>
    int(2)
    [7]=>
    int(2)
    [8]=>
    int(7)
  }
}
```

What you get here instead, is an array of arrays, where the keys represent the unique set of values to which you have an array of random numbers.